# Script to add to BAT file so output could show from a jar that sweeps web

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar, scheduler

Let’s say I have a java jar file called sweep.jar that I run every hour using Windows Task Scheduler to collect data from websites and save to text file.

In order to run it—the script is saved in a Windows Batch File named start.bat

start java -cp java -jar "C:\folder\sweep.jar" main.sweep

Here’s my dilemma:

Option 1:
If I simply manually click on the start.bat file using the cursor, a black screen CMD window opens and shows the output of the sweep.jar file as it goes to select websites and sweeps data saves to text file.

Option 2:
If the sweep.jar file is run via the Task Scheduler on schedule, it runs fine except no black screen CMD window opens; but the jar runs in the background and still saves the results to text files.
How can I have it both ways?  Run the jar via Task Scheduler and still have the output show simultaneously as it run in the black screen CMD window.  What specific script am I needing to add onto the BAT file? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Run the Scheduled Task as a specific user, only when they are logged in, and certainly not with highest privileges.

Comment: It's a top priority job that needs to run regardless.  Need it run whether logged in or not. Pseudo mission critical type. Please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: A batch file processed by `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` started by `explorer.exe` on double clicking the batch file or by the __Task Scheduler__ using the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with option `/c` and the batch file name appended as command to execute and then close `cmd.exe` just to use its internal command `start` resulting in using once again `CreateProcess` to run `java.exe` after having found it in current directory or in a folder in `PATH` is not needed.

Comment: By default if not something other configured a scheduled task is run with the built-in __SYSTEM__ account in an environment with no graphical user interface available at all. For that reason no console window can be opened by `CreateProcess` on starting `cmd.exe` to process the batch file. There must be change in properties of the scheduled task to use your user account and run the batch file every hour only when you are logged in to have an execution environment on which a graphical user interface exists at all. In other words the Windows shell must be loaded on task execution.

Comment: The Windows shell is by default `explorer.exe` started after a user signs in/logs in with Windows desktop, Windows Start menu and Windows taskbar with system tray as visible graphical user interface. The __Action__ of the scheduled task should be configured to run the __program__ `"C:\Program Files\Java\bin\java.exe"` (or whatever is the correct fully qualified file name on your PC) with __optional arguments__ being `-cp java -jar "C:\folder\sweep.jar" main.sweep` and __Start in__ being the full path of the folder without `"` to use as current directory on starting `java.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Compo gave you the only reasonable answer: "Run the Scheduled Task as a specific user, only when they are logged in, and certainly not with highest privileges."

Allowing services to interact with the desktop opens a pandora's box of security holes. That box used to be open and Microsoft has been trying to close it for years.

These articles help explain why these restrictions are in place:

https://serverfault.com/questions/576144/allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop

https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/interact-with-desktop/